# Firestore real-time listener with GeoQuery in Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have events in my app that I'd like to display on a map view. In my app, events are associated with a particular location (CLLocationCoordinate2D).

The current implementation is as follows: When the user scrolls the map, i.e. changes the map's coordinateRegion, I have a Combine subscriber function that debounces for 2 seconds and fetches all events within 50 km. I'm using the GeoFire obj-c library ported to Swift. The implementation is as follows:

```
func fetchEventsInRegion() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async { [coordinateRegion, weak self] in
            let coordinates = CLLocation(coordinateRegion.center)
            let queryBounds = GFUtils.queryBounds(
                forLocation: coordinateRegion.center, withRadius: 50_000.0
            )
            let queries = queryBounds.map { queryBound -> Query in
                return Firestore.firestore().collection("Events")
                    .whereField("isActive", isEqualTo: true)
                    .whereField("isPublic", isEqualTo: true)
                    .order(by: "locationHash").start(at: [queryBound.startValue]).end(at: [queryBound.endValue])
            }
            var counter = 0
            var eventsInRegion: [DBEvent] = []
            for query in queries {
                query.getDocuments { [weak self] querySnapshot, _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        counter += 1
                        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                            return
                        }
                        for document in documents {
                            if let event = try? document.data(as: DBEvent.self) {
                                let eventLocation = CLLocation(event.location)
                                if GFUtils.distance(from: coordinates, to: eventLocation) <= 50_000.0 {
                                    eventsInRegion.append(event)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        eventsInRegion = eventsInRegion.filter { event in
                            return event.startTime > Date()
                        }
                        if counter == queries.count {
                            self?.eventsInRegion = eventsInRegion
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

func fetchEventsInRegionSubscriber() {
        $coordinateRegion
            .debounce(for: .seconds(2.0), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .map { [weak self] _ in
                self?.fetchEventsInRegion()
            }
            .sink { _ in
                ()
            }
            .store(in: &setOfSubscribers)
    }
```

This function is defined inside this (simplified) class:

```
class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var coordinateRegion: MKCoordinateRegion

    @Published var eventsInRegion: [DBEvent] = []

    var setOfSubscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
}
```

The DBEvent struct is a struct that holds all the information about the event.

Right now, this function re-fetches all events within 50 km of the map's center location whenever the user scrolls (with a debounce of 2 seconds). Ideally I'd like to implement a Firestore listener that listens to events in the database conditional to the map's center location. Somehow I need to update the locationHash of the geoquery inside the listener. Is this possible?

In this way, there's no need to refetch events when the user has scrolled and the events in the coordinateRegion has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow I need to update the locationHash of the geoquery inside the listener. Is this possible?

Firestore queries are immutable, so if you want to query a different range - you will have to create a new query for that.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. Could I ask what would be your preferred approach for implementing this functionality?

Comment: There's no preference here: if you want to update the geo-region that you query, you will need to create new queries for the geohash ranges of the new region.